# How to return which element from the tuple matched in the endswith function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, ends-with

I am trying to make a file renamer using Python. I was able to successfully scrape Wikipedia for list of episodes, but while making the renamer file I was met with a lot of discrepancies. What I want is that instead of '.mkv' at the end I want to use exactly the extension that was matched from the if condition. Is there a way to return it?

```
extensions = ('.webm','.mkv','.flv','.vob','.ogv', 
  '.ogg','.drc','.gif','.gifv','.mng','.avi','.mov', 
  '.qt','.wmv','.yuv','.rm','.rmvb','.asf','.amv','.mp4',
  '.m4p', '.m4v','.mpg', '.mp2', '.mpeg', '.mpe', '.mpv',
  '.mpg', '.mpeg', '.m2v','.m4v','.svi','.3gp','.3g2','.mxf',
  '.roq','.nsv','.f4v', '.f4p', '.f4a' ,'.f4b','.srt')
list = f.readlines()


y = 0
num = 1
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(extensions):
      os.rename(path+"\\"+filename,path+"\\"+str(num)+' - '+list[int(y)].strip('\n')+'.mkv') #instead of mkv, I want extension which was matched in the above if condition. 
    y += 1
    num += 1
```

Comment: So if I understood you are seeking broken extensions like `.mp` and "repairing" them with items from list?

Comment: you can use `os.path.splitext` to extract the extension of a path https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext.

Comment: @zipa No, I just want to see which extension matched, for eg, I have a files test.mp4 and test2.mkv then when the extension from the extension matches I want it to be returned. [i.e. test.mp4 matches, then I want .mp4 as a return value]

Comment: @EricDuminil it works for me.

Comment: @AyushMandowara: My bad, I don't know how I tested it. It does indeed work.

Comment: @EricDuminil there was an extra 's' in endswith :P sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well either you have to loop over the extensions one by one, or you could split the filename to get the extension.

**Split by filename**

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endsswith(extensions):
        extension = filename.split('.')[-1] # you can use os.path.splitext too as Max Chretien suggested
        # ...
```

**Use explicit loop**

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    matching_extensions = filter(lambda extension: filename.endswith(extension), extensions)
    if matching_extensions:
        extension = matching_extensions[0]
    # ...
```

Comment: I used the first method, minimum change in my code :)

Answer (score 1):

Another lead, first I will extract the `filename` and `file_extension` using [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

Then if the `file_extension` matches your `extensions` tuple I will rename it with a `try` `except` to see if there is any errors.

```
for file_path in os.listdir(path):
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    if file_extension in extensions:
      try:
          os.rename(file_path, filename + '.mkv')
      except OSError:
          print("Error while renaming {}".format(filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, probably the following code might work.

```
extensions = ('.webm','.mkv','.flv','.vob','.ogv', 
  '.ogg','.drc','.gif','.gifv','.mng','.avi','.mov', 
  '.qt','.wmv','.yuv','.rm','.rmvb','.asf','.amv','.mp4',
  '.m4p', '.m4v','.mpg', '.mp2', '.mpeg', '.mpe', '.mpv',
  '.mpg', '.mpeg', '.m2v','.m4v','.svi','.3gp','.3g2','.mxf',
  '.roq','.nsv','.f4v', '.f4p', '.f4a' ,'.f4b','.srt')
list = f.readlines()


y = 0
num = 1
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if ('.'+filename.lower().split('.')[1]) in list(extensions):
        os.rename(path+"\\"+filename,path+"\\"+str(num)+' - '+list[int(y)].strip('\n')+'.mkv')
    y += 1
    num += 1
```

I just made one minor changes to your code.

from: `if filename.endswith(extensions):`

to: `if ('.'+filename.lower().split('.')[1]) in list(extensions):`

Hope it helps!

Comment: it would be better to use `split('.')[-1]`, as there can be multiple periods in the filename as well. (ex: breaking.bad.s02.e02.mp4)
Here, we only want the "mp4" part, and hence, `split(".")[-1]` would do the trick! (Split on period, and get the last element of the list)